# PHPStorm ругается на JQuery

Tags: phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такое происходит и как исправить?

Comment: Возможно, у вас не подключен jQuery

Comment: пометить папку корня как resource root мб ?

Comment: @Voprositel у меня в проекте jQuery подключена через CDN. Но разве в IDE нет встроенной JQuery?

Comment: @Елена, jQuery не имеет особого синтаксиса, это просто библиотека. phpstorm просто не видит объекта `$` и ругается на это.

Comment: подключайте как угодно. но локальная копия никогда не помешает

Comment: @teran так и сделала. спасибо